# How to use GUI while threads doing their jobs in QT?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

As a self-learner, I am trying to understand `QThread` logics in c++ with `QT`. I wrote simple thread class which has for loop inside. However when thread is inside for loop I cannot use MainWindow. To try it I open `QFileDialog` and select some files. When I press "`Open`" button thread runs and `FileDialog` is not closing until thread finish his job.

Is it possible to use MainWindow while thread is working background?

Here is simple code for my try..

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog *lFileDialog = new QFileDialog(this, "Select Folder", "/.1/Projects/", "*");

    QStringList selectedFileNames = lFileDialog->getOpenFileNames(this, "Select Images", "/home/mg/Desktop/", "", 0, 0);

    if(!selectedFileNames.isEmpty())
    {
        MyThread mThread1;
        mThread1.name = "thread1";
        mThread1.run();
        mThread1.wait();
    }
}


void MyThread::run()
{
    for (int var = 0; var < 100000; ++var)
    {
        qDebug() << this->name << var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is all running on the main thread. I suggest you read up about QThread in the documentation. [This article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) is also very good.

Comment: In practice, a good practice is to make worker classes from QObject that owns the thread, which receives requests, does the job, and notify on completion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't `wait()` on the thread in your click handler!
Also, you don't call a thread's `run` yourself, you just start the thread. Starting the thread will call `run()`.

Comment: sorry, I missed your call to run, too. See my edid, @goGud.

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean about run() :(. Could you give me simple example or another explanation ?

Comment: don't call `run()`! Use `start()` instead, and most importantly read the article that TheDarkKnight linked to or at least the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) of QThread.

Comment: Oh... you are right. I have last question. I moved mThread1.wait() in constructor, and moved creating object MyThread mThread1; in mainwindow.h file. It is good way to use or not?

Comment: Why are you doing that at all? Waiting on a thread is definitely not very Qt-logical. **you should read @TheDarkKnight 's article**: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example of using a thread for code that blocks. The main thread remains interactive and outputs `tick...` every second until the thread is done. When the tread is finished, it cleanly quits.

While I demonstrate a console application, this could just as easily be a GUI application and the GUI thread would not be blocked at any point.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cstdio>

class MyThread : public QThread {
  void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    sleep(10); // block for 10 seconds
  }
public:
  MyThread(QObject * parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {}
  ~MyThread() {
    wait(); // important: It's illegal to destruct a running thread!
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTextStream out(stdout);
  MyThread thread;
  QTimer timer;
  timer.start(1000);
  QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&out]{
    out << "tick..." << endl;
  }
  app.connect(&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));
  thread.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```